# How should I architect serperate login areas / web applications using the same membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I currently have a web application, lets call it "WebApp-A".

WebApp-A implements the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and AspNetSqlRoleProvider.

I now want to create a second web application, lets call it "SubApp-B" and have it nested inside WebApp-A as such:

WebApp-A/SubApp-B

I would like SubApp-B to implement the same AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and AspNetSqlRoleProvider.

I would like users created under SubApp-B to be able to log into WebApp-A, but users created under WebApp-A to NOT be able to log into SubApp-B. I would also like to be able to assign roles from WebApp-A to SubApp-B users.

To my understanding I can use the same AspNetSqlMembershipProvider with multiple web applications and differentiate users using the applicationName="" inside of the respective web.config's. Would this approach satisfy my above requirements?

Should I even be nesting SubApp-B as a web-application inside WebApp-A. OR should I just be using WebApp-A with roles to create users that can access the /SubFolder area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like users created under SubApp-B to be able to log into
>   WebApp-A, but users created under WebApp-A to NOT be able to log into
>   SubApp-B. I would also like to be able to assign roles from WebApp-A
>   to SubApp-B users.

If a user is created under **SubApp-B**, then assign a special role (let say **SubAppBRole**) to the user .

When a user access **SubApp-B**, check to make sure the user is in the **SubAppBRole**.

In other words, a user created under **WebApp-A** are not in **SubAppBRole**, and they won't be able to loing to **SubApp-B**

> To my understanding I can use the same AspNetSqlMembershipProvider
>   with multiple web applications and differentiate users using the
>   applicationName="" inside of the respective web.config's. Would this
>   approach satisfy my above requirements?

No. You cannot set **WebApp-A** and **SubApp-B** in different **ApplicaitionName**. If you want a **WebApp-A** user to be able to log-in to **SubApp-B**, the user needs to be in same **ApplicaitionName**.

> Should I even be nesting SubApp-B as a web-application inside
>   WebApp-A. OR should I just be using WebApp-A with roles to create
>   users that can access the /SubFolder area?

You can nest two ASP.Net sites although I personally do not like it. Sometime, [FormAuthentication domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.cookiedomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives problem if you try SSO. Besides, configuration setting in two web.config files might collide each other. However, once you configure it properly, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was not sure about using ApplicationName. However, after testing it and the information you provided, it makes more sense. :)